# Работа с удаленным репозиторием git

Tags: git, yii2, debian

Добрый день!
Помогите разобраться с git и удаленным репозиторием.
Задача такая. Есть основной сервер, на котором крутится nginx и сайт на yii2. Адрес **/usr/share/nginx/html/yii**
Разработка будет вестись удаленно на виртуалке несколькими людьми.
Т.е. там аналогичная система с адресом **/usr/share/nginx/html/yii**
Сначала разрабатываем у себя локально на виртуалке, потом, если все хорошо, пушим на основном сервер.

Так вот, проблема в том, что если я на основном сервере добавляю git без bare

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/yii
git init
git add .
git commit 'my first commit'
```

Далее на виртуалке пробую клонировать

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
git clone root@IP:/usr/share/nginx/html/yii
touch test.php
git add test.php
git commit -m 'test.php'
git push
```

То ругнется на то

> refusing to update checked out branch refs/heads/master

Становится ясным то, что нельзя писать в текущую non-bare ветку.
Если ставить git bare

```
git --bare init
```

То в корне сайта будет много левых файлов, как config, HEAD и прочее
Если создать с именем

```
git --bare init yii.git
```

То не будет обновлений на сайте.
Я уже запутался пробую все варианты.
Каким образом организовать работу основного сервера и разработка на виртуалках посредством git?
Примерный рисунок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Настроил я такую схему.

Основная логика в том, что у себя локально (на виртуалке) создаем репозиторий

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/yii2 <-- (тут находится мой сайт)
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'My first commit'
```

Теперь на основном сервере (куда мы хотим пушить со своей виртуалки) создаем bare-репозиторий

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
mkdir yii2.git
cd yii2.git
git init --bare  <-- создавать можно где угодно, я создал на 1 директорию выше основного сайта, потом только в nginx запретить надо
cd hooks <-- переходим в папку хуков
touch post-receive <-- создаем хук для записи в основной сайт из bare-репозитория
nano post-receive <-- редактируем хук
```

Тут указывает путь к сайту на виртуалке (не bare-репозиторий, а основной на виртуалке)

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> GIT_WORK_TREE=/usr/share/nginx/html/yii2 git checkout -f
> ```

```
chmod +x hooks/post-receive <--ставим права
```

Теперь на виртуалке добавляем удаленный репозиторий

```
git remote add origin ssh://root@IP:port:/usr/share/nginx/html/yii2.git <-- ссылка на наш bare-репозиторий на основном сервере
git push origin +master:refs/heads/master
```

Вообще, у вас в конфиге гита должно быть подобное (это на виртуалке)

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/yii2/.git
cat config
```

> ```
> [core]
>         repositoryformatversion = 0
>         filemode = true
>         bare = false
>         logallrefupdates = true
> [remote "origin"]
>         url = ssh://root@IP:port/usr/share/nginx/html/yii2.git
>         fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> [branch "master"]
>         remote = origin
>         merge = refs/heads/master
> ```

Теперь если запушить с виртуалки, то все должно сработать

```
git push origin
```

Вот и все. Эта связка работает с 2-х виртуалок (с eclipse) и 1 основной сервер.